# Kendo Grid Re-positioning After PopUp Edit update/cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a custom edit template on a kendo grid. The grid contains a couple hundred records. There is no paging and relies on the browser scroller to view records near the bottom of the page. Depending on the position of the record I edit, the window will re-position its scroller making it difficult to keep track of where you previously edited. I have managed to save the position of the window scroll

with jquery

```
 position = $(window).scrollTop();
```

I want to then use

```
$(window).scrollTop(position);
```

to restore the position. In the console the restore works fine, but no matter what event I bind the above code to it still re-positions my scroll. Is there some event that fires that is grid independent after a update/cancel edit/add?

Comment: Can you please post some more code?

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a reproducible example makes it a bit hard. Using my own test it seems to work fine.

You can try this:

```
function someEvent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ... your reposition code
}
```

Sometimes using a timeout works, so your code runs slightly after Kendo's.

```
function someEvent(e) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        ... your reposition code
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: So it turns out is was something to do with having the grid be navigable property set to true. Once I no longer supported keyboard navigation the issue cleared itself up.

Comment: Hah, that's interesting. Please add and mark yours as an answer so other's can find it. :)